# Нужна ли запятая перед И?

Tags: синтаксис, пунктуация

"Мне 42 года(,) и я совсем одна" — по идее, запятая нужна. Но, с другой стороны, речь идет об одном и том же человеке. Можно ли считать это предложение сложносочиненным?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да, это сложносочинённое предложение. Первое простое - односоставное безличное, второе - двусоставное. Запятая нужна. То, что речь идёт об одном и том же человеке, никак не влияет на постановку знаков.

Answer (score 1):

Да, нужна. Предложение можно разбить на два предложения, поставив точку, вместо запятой.